# Normal shell vs subshell vs "bash -c" last command exit code

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to get the exit code of the last command chained with `&&` and `||` correctly.

I encountered a strange behavior that I cannot explain. Please help.

This is my `exit-code.sh` test script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "running exit-code with $1"
exit $1
```

This works as expected:

```
$ ./exit-code.sh 1 && ./exit-code.sh 2 && ./exit-code.sh 3 || echo last exit code: $?
running exit-code with 1
last command exit code: 1
```

The same with `()` to run it in a subshell:

```
$ (./exit-code.sh 1 && ./exit-code.sh 2 && ./exit-code.sh 3 || echo last exit code: $?)
running exit-code with 1
last exit code: 1
```

But:

```
$ /bin/bash -c "./exit-code.sh 1 && ./exit-code.sh 2 && ./exit-code.sh 3 || echo last exit code: $?"
running exit-code with 1
last exit code: 0
```

Why do I get exit code 0 here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why do I get exit code 0 here?

The reason is that with the double quotes, parameter expansion (of the special parameter, `$?`) is carried out before passing arguments to the new Bash process. If you turn on debug and verbose mode, you can see this clearly:

```
$ set -xv
$ bash -c "(./exit-code.sh 1 && ./exit-code.sh 2 && ./exit-code.sh 3 || echo last exit code: $?)"
bash -c "(./exit-code.sh 1 && ./exit-code.sh 2 && ./exit-code.sh 3 || echo last exit code: $?)"
+ bash -c '(./exit-code.sh 1 && ./exit-code.sh 2 && ./exit-code.sh 3 || echo last exit code: 0)'
running exit-code with 1
last exit code: 0
$ set +xv
```

In this case `$?` is set to `0` because the previous command (`set -xv` in this example) executed successfully.

Answer (score 3):

Quotes

Just use single ' quotes

```
/bin/bash -c './exit-code.sh 1 && ./exit-code.sh 2 && ./exit-code.sh 3 || echo last exit code: $?'

running exit-code with 1
last exit code: 1
```